# Update price in add-to-cart button (Woocommerce + Extra Product Option)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've added some code to my `functions.php` file to add the price of my products in my add to cart button (on product pages). But right now, when i'm using Extra Product Options (by Themehigh) and add some product options, the price is not updating ...

Example : Let's say the product is 10$ right now. If the user checks an option that costs 1$, the price is still 10$ and not 11$ ...

Here is the custom code i'm using for displaying the price in the add-to-cart buttons :

```php
// Add price to add to cart button
add_filter('woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'custom_add_to_cart_price', 20, 2); // Shop and other archives pages
add_filter('woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'custom_add_to_cart_price', 20, 2); // Single product pages
function custom_add_to_cart_price($button_text, $product)
{
    // Variable products
    if ($product->is_type('variable')) {
        // shop and archives
        if (!is_product()) {
            $product_price = wc_price(wc_get_price_to_display($product, array('price' => $product->get_variation_price())));
            return $button_text . ' - ' . strip_tags($product_price);
        }
        // Single product pages
        else {
            return $button_text;
        }
    }
    // All other product types
    else {
        $product_price = wc_price(wc_get_price_to_display($product));
        return $button_text . ' - ' . strip_tags($product_price);
    }
}
```

And here is the code in my `woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/simple.php` file that displays the buttons :

```html
<button type="submit" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo esc_attr($product->get_id()); ?>" class="ms-btn-primary">
    <div class="btn-span">
        <span class="btn-arrow">
            <svg x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 10 10">
                <circle id="Oval" fill="#ffffff" cx="5" cy="5" r="5"></circle>
            </svg>
        </span>
        <?php echo esc_html($product->single_add_to_cart_text()); ?>
    </div>
</button>
```

Comment: The Extra Product Options Pro plugin is supposed to do this programmatically. That's why i didn't talk about jQuery, and thanks i'm aware that StackOverflow isn't a free coding service ;) . I wondered if the issue comes from my custom code

Comment: Your code is ok, but not for client side events that change the product price.

Comment: Do you have any article or material talking about this ? I'm new to javascript, i might admit i have no clue how to achieve this ..